What kind of navy could island nations with populations in the few 100k range build to fight each other in a 1890s-1920s naval technology?
There are several small island nations with populations between about 100 thousand and one million people. They each have one or two central islands with a significant amount of small outlying islands. They are industrialized and have GDPs per capita compared to wealthier industrial European economies of the period, but their economies are obviously limited by their populations and land area.
They are in the era of the 1890s to early 1920s technologically, and are significantly concerned about the prospect of going to war with each other. They know they could not win against any major naval power, so they are largely focused on war with each other. Their major concerns are a mix wars aiming to take a limited amount of territory from others or complete conquest, although notably while some wars aiming to take pieces of territory occur no larger scale attempts at complete conquest actually happen but they continue to remain a concern.
They are willing to sink a large amount of their economy into constructions of their military and there is a serious prospect of war between them. As they are all island nations, their navies are their primary concern. They have access to the full range of naval technology they can afford.
While towards the later part of this time frame air forces come into existence due to the era they have limited payloads and short range (aside from airships) while still being quite expensive, The islands are spread far enough apart that while aircraft could be used as a defensive asset they are not relevant as an offensive asset.
Under these conditions what kind of navies would be most effective for them to build to fight each other?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

When air forces come into existence, why would they not benefit from the developments seen across the Western world, throughout and after WW1?
Who says by 1920, aircraft had 'limited payloads' or 'short range' or were still 'quite expensive?
How far apart are your islands that aircraft are not relevant in offence?
The problem seems to be not that you really can't tell, but that you can't choose either of the two obvious options:
Please, either build your own world, or do the simple research… which would show countries like yours did really exist in that period

@RobbieGoodwin I have spent a long time looking for nations similar to waht i am talking about. They did not exist. I cannot find an example of nation a that was located on islands, had populations between 100,000 and 1,000,000, was industrialized, and worried about conflict with other similar such nations around 1890-1920. You can find nations with some of those characteristics, but certainly not all of them.

"They did not exist."  This should tell you something about the real-word feasibility of your story.  If you write a compelling story, though, and set the reader's expectations, that won't matter.

If RonJohn was not right - he is - I'd still be asking you to share your views about industrial history.
Does 1890s-1920s naval technology not mean better than iron-clad, wholly iron or steel battleships?
How easily might a mere 100,000 - roughly, a single small city around 1900 - have 'industrialised' on the scale you imagine?
Around then Manchester - one of the most commercially successful cities ever - had a population less than your one million max.
Could Manchester have been so successful without more than 100 years of history and 30-some million neighbours?

Trying to collate some of my comments into an answer.
None of your countries builds warships themselves. The great powers of your world have more experience, better R&D, and better economies of scale, and probably don't have to import so much material. Even if your countries have the industrial capability to build warships, it's more efficient for them to purchase from a major power and use their industry in other ways. You can observe this in real world navies, both at the time in question and the present day.
What ships would they have - probably no dreadnoughts. Your bigger ~1M countries probably have a few destroyers, perhaps even a couple armored cruisers, and yes, landing craft (which they might build themselves) as noted by Richard Kirk. Your smaller ~100K countries are unlikely to be attempting invasions, their focus is on not getting eaten. That means they go for torpedo boats, possibly submarines, minefields, shore batteries - everything to make it too painful for a bigger country to land an invasion force. See the Russo-Japanese war for contemporary real-world battles and effectiveness of torpedo boats even against bigger ships.
Regarding submarines - your bigger countries probably have a few, they may be too expensive to operate for your smaller countries (even if they theoretically could, what's better - one or two subs, or several more torpedo boats?). Anti-submarine warfare until the second half of the First World War was basically "hope to catch them on the surface and sink them with guns", depth charges and hydrophones developed slowly enough that the first submerged U-Boat wasn't sunk until 1916. Now that's technically still in your time period, but near the end and your countries aren't first-rate powers, so most likely they don't have access to anti-submarine technology and are still trying to catch them on the surface (early subs can't stay underwater very long yet, so this isn't as hopeless as it sounds).
Incidentally, although older ships continued in service, which means we can attempt an answer, there's a huge difference in naval technology between 1890 and 1920, I'm not sure you could pick a 30-year period with more development. If we take the start of this period then nobody is using submarines yet, although a few countries are actively developing them.
Edit: as vsz noted, they may prefer to purchase older ships at a discount or even accept them as "gifts" in exchange for some favours, but they can also probably commission some new ships - consider the naval arms race between Brazil-Argentina-Chile during this era. Those countries are all a few times bigger than your biggest ones but also less developed than you seemingly want yours to be, so the budget difference may not be that big, and your countries probably won't be ordering some of the bigger ships anyway.

"consider the naval arms race between Brazil-Argentina-Chile during this era."  This is exactly what I was thinking while reading his wish.

How about...

Landing craft

If you are going to war with an island state, you are wanting to occupy their island. This will have to be done by the army. These may need an escort. Can be re-purposed civilian craft, such as the Roll-on-roll-off ferries I the Falklands war.

Buy second-hand cruiser from major powers.

This will offer no significant threat to the major powers, but this will probably be better than an island nation could build for themselves unless they have coal and iron ore.

Submarines.

A popular option for the naval underdog. See for example The Fenian Ram - a submarine developed by Irish nationalists in 1881 for use against the British, the German 'U' boats of WWI and II, and the Italian Caproni CB class. Can sink many times their own weight of enemy ships. Also useful as an escort for landing craft.

Torpedo Boats

Suggested in the comments, and added here. Good for island defence and short-range escort duty.

Torpedo boats.  The 1890s-1920s was the golden age of torpedo boats.

What would they use to destroy eachothers submarines? They're not underdogs, as stated in the question they aren't aiming to fight the major powers, they're aiming to fight other nations with similar resource limitations.

Yep. Torpedo boats. Good for island defence and short-range escort duty.
In the 1920's the Royal Navy disliked and distrusted submarine warfare. There were brave pioneers, but most naval people on the surface saw it as being 'sneaky' and 'ungentlemanly'. This attitude handed an advantage to the submarine users. If you have limited manufacturing ability, submarines may seem attractive. They are probably not 'hunter-killers'. They would be a defence against invading surface ships.

1890s-1920s is far too early for dedicated landing craft outside of small scale experiments. Amphibious assaults were largely improvised until D-Day.

@SPavel you have a point but you're overstating it. Dedicated landing craft are a WW1 innovation (yes, I had to look this up), which is technically in the time period, "largely improvised until D-Day" is pretty far off. Still, you're probably right in that smaller powers don't have them. They can definitely build flat-bottomed barges though.

Those flat-bottomed landing will get a mile or two before being swamped..

An archipelago nation like described in the question will likely have a large number of fishing boats, ferries and small scale passenger vessels that can be pressed into service. Considering the era, and the setting I don't expect tanks at the landing and other heavy stuff like artillery can be kept at sea until a harbor is secured. So I don't see that much need to waste resources on specialized landing craft.

Many would have difficulty building more than one or two war ships.
They could certainly sustain some fishing boats or smaller wooden boats for warfare, but 100k people isn't enough to sustain a shipping industry. The larger nations could perhaps build one easily, or ten or so by devoting everything to it.
Britain had 400 million people backing it, and vast tax reserves from them, and had around 400 ships in 1900s. A million people per ship. That was using 10% of their military budget. Each of these nations have a tenth of the people.
If these smaller nations use 100% of their budget and have higher taxation they might be able to build one or two battlecruisers. They could surround these with numerous converted civilian ships with cannons and rifles. The battlecruisers would act as fast and deadly ships which could easily sweep up fleets of enemy ships and control islands, while the other ships would harass and scout as needed.
The larger nations would have a massive advantage of course, and be able to crush smaller nations. The battlecruisers would at least mean they could compete. The range of torpedos and smaller artillery is lower back at that tech level, so outside of mist and ambush, larger ships have a huge advantage. The smaller nations would need to rely on heavily fortified coastal bases and radio communication and alliances to survive larger nations, and pool their ships for attacks.

Why only build battlecruisers? What conditions mean they shouldn't build destroyers, torpedo boats gunboats, and protected, light armoured, coastal defence ships or armoured cruisers? You didn't really explain why they should build one larger ship rather than building smaller ones. Even countries the size of Sweden or Greece never built a large capital ship. Also, they don't all have 100k, they range from 100 thousand to a bit over a million.

If you build small ships, the enemy can just sweep you up with their larger ships, which have much greater concentration of firepower.

A battlecruiser without serious escort is not going to survive a torpedo attack by a squadron of torpedo boats or destroyers without escort by destroyers of it's own. A capital ship without escort can easily concentrate enough firepower to take on one or a few cruisers but a group of torpedo vessels can easily bring far more firepower against a capital ship than the capital ship can against them when the capital ship has no escort preventing them from getting in close to utilize their torpedo. Without escort a capital ship is more vulnerable than any other type of ship.

As I mentioned, you would have numerous converted civilian ships to harass. They would prevent easy close ranged torpedo attacks, which at this stage were very close ranged attacks. Large ships can carry heavy artillery which can easily blast lots of ships at extreme range, and powerful engines that can outrun enemy ships.

How well are those converted civilian ships going to actually go against an actual destroyer or protected/light cruiser? Auxiliary merchant cruisers were big but they usually could only fit a very limited number of guns and had 0 armour while not being all that fast.

Not very well, but the light cruiser and the destroyer would do even worse against the battle cruiser.

Once it's escorts are defeated a group of destroyers or large torpedo boats will easily make a battlecruiser very unhappy with torpedos though. The entire reason destroyers were created is because larger vessels are horribly vulnerable to destroyers and torpedo boats .

The UK had only 41 million people in 1900. Are you counting the entire British Empire to reach 400 million?

I'm with the OP on this one, what you're suggesting is very much all your eggs in a single basket that's very vulnerable to a night attack with torpedoes - see the battle of Tsushima. The very biggest countries might have a couple battlecruisers, or more likely older armored cruisers, but not unless they can afford proper supporting ships. They'd be better off with no cruisers and a few destroyers. Didn't downvote but I don't think this is a good answer.

The battle of Tsushima had the notable tactical mistake that the Russians went in radio silence in enemy territory in mist, and got ambushed. Their composition doesn't matter a lot. Outside of mist you have an extreme range advantage with a big ship and torpedo ships and destroyers have a major range disadvantage. If you don't have that you're likely to lose any conflict with a larger nation, Larger vessels are vulnerable now to smaller vessels because of range improvements, but they were less vulnerable in the past when artillery was the king of range.

OK, if you want another example, how about the Szent Istvan - sunk by two Italian torpedo boats, which both got away, despite an escort of cruisers, destroyers and torpedo boats. Or the Pommern, sunk by torpedoes from a destroyer at Jutland. There's a laundry list of capital ships sunk by submarines during WW1. Do you want one lucky shot to sink your only real fighting ship? I think you're seriously underestimating how vulnerable a capital ship is without proper escort.

You're also overestimating the range advantage - sure, it's there, but a small and fast torpedo boat isn't an easy target at long range, and possibly only one needs to get close. Darkness, or as you noted, mist, significantly reduce that advantage. If you have to run for home every time there's a fog or it gets dark, your fancy battlecruiser isn't going to be very effective. Note as well that there are rather few RL examples precisely because ships were escorted. I don't think your converted civilian ships are going to be very effective.

Szent was 1918 and in a strait where they had much less range, Pommern was an ambush at night in 1916, In general this was the era where torpedos started to have more range, but you asked for the period of 1890 to 1920. For most of that era, they were not very effective. Even for submarines, they mostly took out trade ships, war ships could just sail around them due to their limited range and at Jutland say they didn't even play a role.

A fog, a strait, an ambush at night - that's the point. Your one warship is very limited in where it can go and when. You can't just sail around where a sub might be lurking if you need to support an invasion fleet. It takes just one or two things to go wrong and you have no navy. Britain lost two battleships to U-boats in the first half of 1915, after losing four cruisers in the first month of the war. That's still with pre-war technology and very much in the 1890s-1920s range the OP asked for.

FWIW, I do think a battlecruiser or two is plausible. A fairly wealthy country of 1M on a war footing probably could afford to buy them along with some actual warships (destroyers and torpedo boats) to support them. I just think the idea of one supership and a bunch of converted civilian ships is a really bad one.

There won't be anybody to man those big ships.

@NepeneNep  Look also at the naval side of the Falklands War - I know its much more recent, but there the threat of just two submarines, coupled with a single sinking lead to the entire Argentine navy deciding not to engage. Every navy ever, has built a pyramid of ships, for a good reason.

The larger threat of submarines emerged fully by ww2, and they started taking precautions mid ww1. That said, in ww1 they hard countered submarines by just avoiding them due to their very limited range. People complain a lot about ambushes and night attacks, but you can just avoid engaging at night and during mist, and then submarines have very little threat with ww1 tech. Small ships got deadly when range got larger, so a few small ships could ambush a larger ship.

@NepeneNep you can try to argue each case but the fact is that there are many examples where things went wrong and ships got sunk by torpedoes. If you try to avoid every dangerous circumstance, then you end up with a small-scale Tirpitz - more powerful than anything afloat, but useless because it's afraid to go outside.

You're also badly underestimating WW1 submarines - those already in service at the start of the war had ranges in the thousands of miles. The problem they had was very limited underwater range, and spending a lot of time on the surface in enemy-controlled waters is dangerous, but a relatively small island country is going to have a hard time hiding its fleet (Britain moved its fleet to Northern Ireland but they probably don't have that option). "Submarines have very little threat with ww1 tech" is objectively, empirically wrong. https://uboat.net/wwi/ships_hit/warships.html

Numbers by analogy.
For numbers, look at Albania in 1930, swap the importance of the army and the navy, and divide it by three or so for population sizes. That would give you perhaps 4,000 naval personnel on active duty. Scaling proportionally, 60 smallish boats. Or 30 smallish boats, 3 to 5 small ships. The price to pay is that there will be fewer ground forces. (Just a citizen milita, or a regular battalion as well? Maybe a few coastal artillery batteries.)
What were navies like in 1900 or 1920?
The time period is historically split by WWI and included much of the arms race before it.
1900 to 1910
Steam turbines were the great new thing, both in torpedo boat destroyers and in dreadnoughts. The performance of torpedoes was iffy, unless fired from a perfect ambush position. Gunnery ranges were limited by targeting and training. Navies did include:

Dreadnoughts and pre-dreadnought battleships. Big guns (same caliber in dreadnoughts, different caliber in pre-dreadnoughts) Obviously much too expensive and too large for your islands.
Armored cruisers. These were smaller than dreadnoughts, but otherwise similar. They could fight anything less than an armored cruiser and win.
Protected cruisers. These had no side armor, just well-placed coal bunkers to give some protection. Cheaper and easier to build than armored cruisers.
Gunboats and sloops. Generally unarmored, with deck guns. Might still carry sails in addition to steam. These were used to 'police' colonial empires.
Torpedo boat destroyers. Smaller than a sloop, faster, armed with torpedoes and a few small cannon. They would support the own battle line against enemy torpedo boats, or attack the enemy battle line.
Torpedo boats. Slower and smaller than destroyers, with just a few torpedoes and perhaps a little gun or two.
Monitors. Coastal or river craft with significant armor for their size and very big guns for their size.

My expectation would be some of the lower-end gunboats and sloops, and perhaps some torpedo boats or monitors. Consider these:

SMS Iltis, a German gunboat.
HMS Calypso, a British corvette, or perhaps something slightly smaller.
SMS Graf Geotzen, a German gunboat on a lake in Africa.
SMS Körös, an Austrian river monitor.

Except for the monitor, what you see there are ships a little bit faster than freighters of the same era, with a few deck guns and machine guns.
Say two or three of these as the "main" force. Having just one would be dangerous, in case it needs an overhaul, but the crew might be insufficient to man all at full strength, and ammo might be in short supply. Two or three armed freighters with room to carry a few companies of troops. Plus a few basically civilian craft with a few small guns.
1920ish
Bigger and better cruisers and battleships, aircraft carriers and submarines are probably bayond the reach of your nations. A tiny submarine like the German-Finnish Vesikko might be a "wonder weapon," but more likely it would be a "white elephant." Some motor gun boats might augment the flotilla.
Or perhaps they might reallocate some of their naval budget to shore-based, fixed-wing aviation. A dozen little biplanes, with wheels or floats, like the Fairey III or the Sopwith Cuckoo. This would not draw much of the manpower pool, but perhaps too many funds to be practical.

Older cruisers and destroyers bought at discount from major powers
If not only the technology, but also geopolitics are similar to the real world historical era, then these nations would be in the sphere of influence of major powers. And if they are both independent and consider going to war with each other, it means they are not fully under the hegemony of one of the major powers, but as the major powers will want to exert some influence in the area, they will use these nations either in proxy wars, or as a projection of power.
As other answers explained, these nations are too small to be able to construct capital ships of the era. However, they could purchase second-rate ships from the major powers. When a major power upgrades the fleet, it will sell some of the older vessels to them. This might even happen at a serious discount, and some vessels might even be gifted, so that the donor Great Power can increase its influence in the area by strengthening its local ally/protectorate.
These nations will then likely end up in the sphere of influence of one major power or another, and the wars between each other might even be proxy wars between the major powers.
What kinds of ships could they have? Take a look at the SMS Emden, which would have been a relatively minor vessel in a battle like the Battle of Jutland, but in East Asia it alone had a really serious effect, and achieved impressive results. So, in an archipelago far from the mainlands of the major powers, an armored cruiser would fill the role of a capital ship, with a couple light or protected cruisers, and up to at most a dozen small destroyers for the bigger nations (here I mean something like the 1893 Daring-class, or the 1903 River-class at most, not giants like the Fletcher) completing the fleet. They would be far too much for them to build, but acquiring such a fleet might be possible by buying (or receiving as "gifts" in exchange for exclusive trade deals) older ships from the major powers.
Then they can complement this fleet with torpedo boats of their own design, which is the only naval vessel they could realistically build themselves.
An interesting example at a smaller scale.
The novel Mathias Sandorf from Jules Verne features an interesting example for a navy of a small island nation. The protagonist founded a small nation on a previously uninhabited and recently purchased private island in the Mediterranean, close to the African coast, in the late 19th century, which gets under attack by pirates organized by the Senusiyya movement. The island's population is only in the few thousands, but as they are fresh settlers, most of them are of military age, and they can muster a defending force of about 500 men.
The islanders have a modern 350-ton steam yacht as their flagship, which was made to order in France, equipped with Hotchkiss revolving cannons, and three small semi-submersible fast torpedo boats of their own design. The attackers have the numerical superiority, coming with a huge fleet mostly composed of small sailing ships, fishing vessels, with a few larger but poorly armed merchant ships, carrying a large landing force to conquer the island. The navy of the defenders cannot stop them entirely from landing troops, but does enough damage to the invading navy that the greatly diminished landing force is finally defeated.
This is a great example of what a small but technologically very advanced island nation can afford: a relatively big ship they purchased in a bigger country, and a few smaller patrol boats they built themselves. And when it comes to fighting, it can involve smaller cargo and fishing vessels pressed into service, usually to land troops or perform boarding actions, as they will lack the firepower to sink enemy vessels quickly.

In 1900 the nation closest to have 100k inhabitants was Luxembourg, counting 250k.
Italy, which was not a naval power but only had the ambition to become one, counted 33 million.
The British Empire, which was THE naval power at the time, counted 400 million.
With such a limited population and economic base, their only option is either guerrilla or piracy targeting commercial routes, not a real naval warfare. Alternatively, they could try getting alliances with stronger navy nation and have them fight in their place.

As stated in the question, they are not aiming to compete with the major naval powers. They are building navies to fight other island nations of similar sizes and with similar resources which also have populations around the 100k to one million range. I already know they have no hope of competing with actual naval powers, and that is not the question.

Gotta dispute something here - Britain was a Naval super-power in the 1700s with just 5 million people. The empire may have had 400 million, but the Royal Navy primarily used people from the UK - 15 million in 1850.

@TheDemonLord but the economy supporting it was bigger than just UK

Of course they would do naval warfare! Just not with Dreadnoughts, but with smaller ships, but they would have specialized warships just like any naval military.

@TheDemonLord and fifty years before that, the Venetian republic with a population of 180K could field a bigger navy than Britain could, again with a wider empire to extract resource from.

Populations in the 100ks? Lets talk about army sizes...
Full mobilization of the US during WW2 had 7% of the population serving in the military. And that took a couple of years to achieve and took a long time to recover from. So its not practical for a nation to remain at full mobilization for a long period of time.
During peace time/not full blown war. It has been closer 0.3% of the population serving in the military. So the core of each your island nations will be that 0.3% multiply that by a population of 100k and you get a grand army of 300.
That's not enough to man 1 large warship.  Most likely your island nations peace time navy is going to look a lot like the US coast guard. Primary purpose will be pollicing national waters looking for people fishing without permits/smugglers. In other words, your peace time army doesn't have experience with naval warfare, and the quickly trained war time army (IE poorly trained) will be less skilled then that.
To be a little hyperbolic, your islands nations experience with warfare is a bunch of rude words between one patrol boat and another. As it is doubtful that our island nations could afford to arm their patrol ships with rocks to chuck at the other guys.

If you want to see what a country can do in peacetime, look at North Korea.  They've got 1.3 million active-duty troops and half a million reserves, for about 7% of the population.  Roughly 5% of the GDP goes to the military.  Yes, it's distorting the economy badly, but they've managed to keep it up for about 70 years.

@Mark Not if this "they are industrialized and have GDPs per capita compared to wealthier industrial European economies of the period"  is true.

Yes with 1890s-1920s tech, society will have invented the haber-bosch process which drastically increased agricultural production per farmer. While society won't have developed the same high standard of living, so there is a window where you that increase in agricultural efficiency/production frees up a portion of the population for other activities.

From what i can find (https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/military-personnel-as-a-share-of-total-population?time=1890..1925) having 0.8%-1.7% of the population in the military in peacetime wasn't unusual. Using 1.7% that means 1,700 for the lower end to 17,000 on the higher end wouldn't be that unreasonable. It feels like people ignoring the few 100 thousand to one million and just going with 100k part Smaller ships like destroyers, avisos, and gunboats and avisos only need 100-175 or so personnel. While a smaller light or scout cruiser would need around 300 or so.

@OT-64SKOT I addressed the smallest case, because it was egregious. Ill admit I am using modern numbers for the percentage. But my numbers come from countries with populations of 100k. Tonga (104K) has 450 soldiers, and 140 sailors.  Aruba (107k) doesn't have a military to speak of, Micronesia (114k) no military, Grenada (116k) no military... Samoa (215k) no military...  Luxembourg (700k) has 900 military personnel. Fiji with a population of 2 million has 6500 soldiers, and 4 boats (not ships).

On the other hand in 1776 the with a population of 2.5 million, the US had a navy consisting of 60 converted merchantmen. And had something like 48 thousand men at its peak. But this is a bit of a special case, as it was a revolution, and a lot of those soldiers were unpaid volunteers fighting for 'freedom' and 'liberty'. The opposing party with a population of 4.8 million only fielded 22 thousand soldiers at their peak. Its very hard to motivate your population to make the sacrifices required for full mobilization in order to make some rich guys richer.

So it is possible.. But that was with 1790s tech, not 1890s... There is a major difference in terms of cost/requirements to make a diesel navy then there is to make a sail navy... If you go backwards in technology a hundred years everything you want to do is a lot more achievable.

@Questor using modern numbers isn't a reasonable proxy, modern armies are generally more technological and smaller in number. Take Germany - in 1900 its army numbered 600,000, just over 1% of the population. Today it's a tenth of that. Most of the countries in your sample are part of alliances (e.g. Luxembourg) or have treaties by which another country is obliged to defend them (e.g. Micronesia) - in 1900 these would simply have been colonies, that's not fashionable now but it's still basically the same system with a bit more autonomy. Aruba is actually still a colony of the Netherlands.

The point is, none of these countries is a reasonable approximation for either 1900s technology or a country facing a need to defend itself from a credible threat, let alone the two together. And of course in wartime those numbers go up even more; if the countries are wealthy enough, they may have ships that aren't normally operational but are maintained to be manned by reserves.

Tiny Nations need tiny warships
As other answers have pointed out, these island nations will not be able to maintain a military of more than about 300-3000 total fighting men, and most of those soldiers will likely be army; so, I'd expect a total available force of 100-1000 men.  It is technically possible for these islanders to aquire large warships from other nations, but manning them is a whole other problem.  WWII warships had an average crew size of 350-3500 men. The problem here is that 0-3 destroyers gives your navy very little coverage.  Islands have a lot more coastline for thier populations than full larger nations meaning that if they invested in the large warships used by the larger nations, the enemy would have a lot of opportunity to  just go around your destroyers because they could not possibly secure the whole coastline.
Instead they would focus on small gunships like the French 1915 class river gunships.  These smaller warships were more like floating tanks than destroyers.  They'd only have 1-2 cannons, thick armor (for thier size), and maybe a few guys on the deck to support with machine guns. Instead of needing hundreds of crewmen, these ships could be fully crewed by 20ish men and at only a fraction of he cost of the bigger ships.  So, instead of 3 or less destroyers, your island nations could field 5-50 of these smaller ships giving them enough spread to defend thier shoreline.
At most I would expect the larger islands to have a single second hand destroyer to server as a flagship, but even the bigger islands will mostly use gunboats.

French Brutale B1915 Gunboat

Armed Merchant Ships:
Even with industrialization, it's unlikely that your nations are going to be building any large, dedicated war ships. A shipyard large enough to build such ships would be a stretch, and would likely be needed to build and maintain large enough merchant ships to maintain trade and shipping (which is likely essential to such nations for enough economic strength to be able to fight wars).
The logical solution, however, is to build merchant ships with strategically-located coal bunkers, minimal armor (like protected cruisers) and limited weapons (but likely the capacity to rapidly add additional guns). In a world that might be filled with rival states and pirates, this level of armament is easily justified. Scaling up a merchant ship is going to be significantly cheaper than building dedicated warships. The initial investment in the merchant vessel is already made, and would have been needed for an industrial marine state anyway.
These merchant ships WILL cost more than regular ships, and be slightly less efficient merchant vessels. They will require slightly more crew, especially if being equipped for war at the time. But then the nation's merchant ships will project the nation's power automatically everywhere their merchant ships go. Every ship captain can also be a captain in your navy, and readily make military decisions that support their state. Everywhere they go, you'll have cannons and marines that will outclass any local mobs or yokel militias (gunboat diplomacy).
The cargo holds will allow these vessels to readily transport war materials or be used as troop transports. The fact that they are merchant vessels normally opens opportunities for surprise attacks, since the ships would be visiting foreign ports anyway and would have an excuse to be in the waters of rival states. The transition from commerce to commerce raider would also be effortless, and commerce would likely be the chief target of naval war between rival oceanic states.
Combined with the small dedicated warships like torpedo boats discussed in other answers, it provides a compromise solution that states of you size can reasonably afford.

Limited metal, coal
If these island nations originated in volcanic processes like most of the small pacific islands. they will have no coal no iron in economical concentrations.
Those islands that have continental crust could have metal and coal that are minable.
Limited wood
Most island nations do not have extensive forests to supply building materials for ships. Several island nations like Easter island, UK, Sardinia ran out or low on wood resources at various times in there histories.
Steam engines expensive
Compare Thrust block to tilting pad fluid berings patented 1905.
The low efficiency of thrust blocks means that steam powered ships are expensive and island nations  with no coal. they would be even more expensive.
Fleet composition.
Due to the above resource constraints the bulk of the fleets will small craft. Polynesian style vessels would be best, that is small ocean capable craft. Through different designs would probably needed for higher latitudes.
Add in less then two dozen prestige hulls purchased from other large nations. Such prestige hulls as clippers, maybe an ironclad maybe a steamship. Where coal burning ships are generally too expensive to operate.
